# NLTK.sem.logic cannot infer logical types of functions given types of argument and result, why?

Tags: python, nltk, linguistics, type-theory, first-order-logic

I am working with NLTK.logic.sem to handle the logical structure of sentences. I also use NLTK to handle inferring the logical types of expressions. The NLTK book has an example of when it cannot infer the type of an expression:

```
read_expr = nltk.sem.Expression.fromstring
expr = read_expr('walk(angus)', type_check=True)
expr.argument
<ConstantExpression angus>
expr.argument.type
>>> e
expr.function
<ConstantExpression walk>
expr.function.type
>>> <e,?>
```

The solution according to NLTK is as follows, just tell the type checker what the type of `walk` is. Obviously you can infer the type of `walk` if the checker is just straight up told what it is.

```
sig = {'walk': '<e, t>'}
expr = read_expr('walk(angus)', signature=sig)
expr.function.type
>>> <e,t>
```

Now I would like to have the type checker actually *infer* the types of functions that I do not explicitly give in a signature, given the type of the arguments and the type of the application of the function to the arguments. However, the type checker cannot seem to do this.

```
sig = {'angus' : 'e', 'walk(angus)' : 't'}
expr = read_expr('walk(angus)', signature=sig)
expr.function.type
>>> <e,?>
```

If I am correct, if `walk(angus)` is type `t` and  `angus` is type `e`, then `walk` can *only* be `<e,t>`. Why can the type checker not infer the type of `walk` in this case? What am I missing?

Comment: A signature only specifies types of atomic expressions. `walk(agnus)` is not an atomic expression, so the type `t` can not be used to infer the type of the component expression. You will notice that the assignment `walk(agnus): t` does not have any effect as `expr.type` just returns `?` as well.